# Rendering a MTLTexture to the Screen

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I have captured a snapshot of a view into a `UIImage`, and passed the corresponding `CGImage` into `MTKTextureLoader.newTexture(CGImage)` to load my view into a `MTLTexture`. I would now like to confirm that if I render this `MTLTexture`, it indeed will display a snapshot of the captured view. How can I render this `MTLTexture` to the screen?

Comment: If you just want to check the contents of the texture, you should be able to Quick Look it in the debugger in Xcode.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Thanks, I was indeed able to check how the texture looks using Xcode's Quick Look feature.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures?language=objc) that contains basic information on how to load and display texture on the screen.